# In iOS - When touching a text field in a scroll view the view can not scroll

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface, scrollview, textfield

When trying to scroll a view by touching and dragging on a text field, similarly to how you would scroll around on the edit contacts view on the iPhone, the view will not move, touching and dragging in between the text fields or off to the side of the text fields in the scroll view works but not when touching a textfield.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `delaysContentTouches` property to `YES` for the `UIScrollView` to which you have added to text field.  This should allow you to scroll if you touch and then drag within a text field.

Comment: I am facing this problem and this answer is not helping me. :(

Comment: Thanks....I spent a lot of time ...after I tried your answer and it worked.... :)

Answer (score 5):

Setting `delaysContentTouches` to `true` didn't work for me either. What did was iterating through the scrollview's gesture recognizers and setting each of their `delaysTouchesBegan` and `cancelsTouchesInView` to `true` and `false`, respectively:

```
scrollView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach {

    $0.delaysTouchesBegan = true; $0.cancelsTouchesInView = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it solution in this situation

```
extension UITableView {

    override public func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {
        if view is UITextField || view is UITextView {
            return true
        }
        return super.touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view)
    }

}
```

Comment: Best solution so far, pretty clean and you get the exactly behavior you expect. Thank you Nick.

Answer (score 1):

try with below approach. Just replace your UIScrollView with ScrollView and adds the code to your project.

**SWIFT 4.1**

```
class ScrollView: UIScrollView {
  override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if type(of: view) == TextField.self || type(of: view) == UITextView.self {
      return true
    }
    return super.touchesShouldCancel(in: view)
  }
}
```