# Touch on UITextField inside UIScrollView prevents scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, uitextfield

I've got a bunch of `UITextFields` inside of a `UIScrollView`, and when the user tries to scroll up or down, if the initial touch occurs inside of a `UITextField`, that text field becomes first responder (on the touch down inside event) and prevents scrolling. Is there a way to tell the `UITextField` to only start editing on a touch up inside event?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please check the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50974706/6588287).

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass UIScrollView and try different things with overriding `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:`. If you return YES, then it should always scroll, but you will never be able to edit the text fields. Perhaps it will work if you return YES when the touch is outside the text field. It might take some tricks to figure that out, since the touch object is not sent to `touchesShouldCancelInContentView`. You might need to catch the touch object at some other point and set a property that indicates it has gone outside the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can trying setting the delaysContentTouches property of the scrollview to NO.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = true
```