# UIScrollView not scrolling with UItextfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am making a normal view where users can update their profiles. I followed these steps to make that view

> 1. Created a new `UIViewController` with xib file
> 2. Added a `UIScrollView` in super view
> 3. Added almost 9 `UITextField` and 1 small `UIWebView`
> 4. Satisfied Autolayout constraints like top `UITextField` will have top, left, right and height constrains and same for all the following
>      controls but last `UITextField` have top, left, right, bottom and height
>      constraints.

Now all the constraints are applied and satisfied but when I run the view and then try to scroll by dragging `UITextField` then scrollview is not scrolling but if I scroll by dragging from some area other than `UITextField` then it is scrolling very nice. Can anybody tell me what can be the main problem?

> Note: there is no code yet other than setting up xib file.
>   A sample project is available on this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/7oqry8yzd9twnp1/TestScroll.zip?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide an example project?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126860/in-ios-when-touching-a-text-field-in-a-scroll-view-the-view-can-not-scroll

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran I tried that solution but in vain.

Comment: @arturdev sample project added

Comment: @Mashhadi In your demo project everything work good on 9.3 simulator

Comment: please check my answer with swift 4 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50974706/6588287). It works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding UIScrollView `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` method will solve this problem.

> According to Apple touchesShouldCancelInContentView is called before
>   scrolling begins if touches have already been delivered to a subview
>   of the scroll view. if it returns NO the touches will continue to be
>   delivered to the subview and scrolling will not occur.

By default this method returns NO if view is a `UIControl`. So the scroll doesn't happens for the UIControls.

If we returns YES from this method the touches will not be delivered to subview, So the scroll will occurs.

So override UIScrollView `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` like following

```
@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView

@end

@implementation MyScrollView

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

NOTE: `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` method only calls if we set the `canCancelContentTouches` property to YES

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed these steps but still touchesShouldCancelInContentView method is not being called

Comment: Did you mentioned the class MyScrollView in the identity inspector.

Comment: Make sure you ticked the "Cancellable Content Touches" property for scroll view in storyboard attributes inspector.

Comment: I did it from attributes inspector and afterwards from the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra parent View for all the textfield in ScrollView.

> Note:
>
> - Give constraints to UIView w.r.t. UIScrollView as Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom and Equal Widths.
> - Also don't forget to add the bottom constraint for last object in UIView w.r.t. UIView (Customize it to approx. 30 since it will not
>     scroll much after finishing the contents).
> - Customize the constraint of UIView bottom w.r.t UIScrollView to 0.

See: [image]

Comment: Tried now but still no luck

Comment: it should work, mine is working..! what problem you are getting now?

Answer (score 0):

Set delayContentTouchesProperty to YES for UIScrollView. This would let you scroll if you touch contents of UIScrollView. 
You can do it either programmatically or from storyboard.

Comment: In my original project i am using XIB and I turned it ON but still no luck

Comment: Try removing height constraint for the textFields

Answer (score 0):

You should use uiview as a superview on uiscrollView ,put all the textfield on uiview and make sure you have all the satisfactory constraints applied on uiview as respect of uiscrollView.