# UIControls don't get immediate focus when nested in uiScrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicontrol

I have a view nested in a scrollview. The visible controls on the initial view are fine but when I scroll down I cannot get focus on the scrolled view unless I select a control[text field] that was visible before scrolling.

I cannot upload images because I don't yet have 10 reputation points.

I have attached a link with screenshots. On the final screenshot, I cannot for example use the "Get Location" or any other textfields or buttons button until I have clicked the very top text field with placeholder text "Postal Code", this was the very bottom on the middle screenshot before scrolling.

https://myobscureview.wordpress.com/2016/06/06/scrollview/

This is driving me crazy.

Kind regards

Wayne

Comment: I think a screenshot would help a lot - I'm struggling to understand what you are sitting with

Comment: try UIscrollView -> UIView -> all the UIControls Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156293/uiscrollview-not-scrolling-with-uitextfields/37160048#37160048

Comment: Unfortunately I need 10 reputation points before I can upload an image