# Setting AutoLayout For UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Setting AutoLayout For UIScroolView

I Tried To Set AutoLayout For UIScrollView

But After Setting AutoLayout It Stops Scroll

Any Help Appreciated

Comment: hi, do see my answer for this post! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156293/uiscrollview-not-scrolling-with-uitextfields/37160048#37160048

Comment: can you please give link ?

Comment: i will also post answer for you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Autolayout to set constraints on my UIScrollview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223021/how-can-i-use-autolayout-to-set-constraints-on-my-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the ScrollView is used to fit and access all the contents. So follow the basic steps if you are dealing with ScrollView.

> 1- First take UIScrollView, then assign constraints as **Top, Leading,
>   Trailing and Bottom** w.r.t. superview or any other view's.
>
> 2- Then you need to drag UIView inside the UIScrollView, then assign
>   constraints to UIView as **Top, Leading, Trailing and Bottom** **(all
>   constant = 0)**  Also Give constraint **Equal Widths** w.r.t.
>   UIScrollView.
>
> 3- Now inside the UIView drag your other Objects Like UILabel,
>   UIButton,.. ETC, And provide respective constraint to them w.r.t.
>   UIView.
>
> 4- Now till this you will get an error as ScrollView need y position,
>   then just do add the **bottom constraint** to the last object inside
>   the UIView w.r.t. UIView and **customize it's constant to approx. 20 or
>   30**. Which will let the scroll up when contents are finished inside the scrollview.

Hope this will help you.